# Problems connecting to cloudcluster mysql with pymysql

Tags: python, pymysql

I have the following code to connect to my cloud host (Note X's are place holders for actual credentials). And yes I have looked around and I have found no usable answer out there

```
import pymysql

try:
    db = pymysql.connect(host='xxxxxxxx', user='xxxxxx', 
                         password='xxxxxx', database='xxxxxxxx',
                         port=xx, connect_timeout=60)
except Exception as e:
    print(f'Failed connection {str(e)}')
```

And I get the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\THEMBEKILE\Desktop\Projects\Cafe Nalla1\dbcreatetable.py", line 10, in <module>
    database="xxxxxxxx", port=xxxxx, connect_timeout=60)
  File "C:\Users\THEMBEKILE\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pymysql\__init__.py", line 94, in Connect
    return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\THEMBEKILE\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pymysql\connections.py", line 325, in __init__
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Users\THEMBEKILE\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pymysql\connections.py", line 598, in connect
    self._get_server_information()
  File "C:\Users\THEMBEKILE\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pymysql\connections.py", line 976, in _get_server_information
    packet = self._read_packet()
  File "C:\Users\THEMBEKILE\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pymysql\connections.py", line 657, in _read_packet
    packet_header = self._read_bytes(4)
  File "C:\Users\THEMBEKILE\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pymysql\connections.py", line 708, in _read_bytes
    CR.CR_SERVER_LOST, "Lost connection to MySQL server during query")
pymysql.err.OperationalError: (2013, 'Lost connection to MySQL server during query')
```

PLEASE NOTE: All credentials are correct, and I have used this exact code for an earlier app just a different database and the same supplier and everything worked fine.

I can connect to the DB using the cmd and this command. Which confuses me even more:
`Sqlcmd -S xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx -d xxxxxxxxxxx -U xxxxxxxxxx -P xxxxxxxx`

Any assistance on the matter will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Post your query. Are you executing `SELECT *` on a large table? Could be because of that. Test the same query again with `SELECT * FROM [table] LIMIT 1`.

Comment: Is the host publicly accessible? Try out this [tool](https://portchecker.co/)

Comment: @SauravPathak I am unable to do that because I'm stilling only trying to connect. The connection to my database is failing

Comment: @tbhaxor He's not hitting exception while connecting. His code would have executed `except` block and printed error message, if it was for connection issue.

Comment: Like @tbhaxor said, check if host is publicly accessible. But don't use his tool. Use `nmap` or any portscanner from your own computer.

Comment: @tbhaxor What an amazing tool, but the port I am using is said to be open so I am connecting to the right port. Thank you though this tool will definetly come in handy.

Comment: The exception is actually in the connection.py in pymysql, I actually didn't notice that the wrong exception was being hit.

Comment: @SauravPathak I can connect to the databases using ```Sqlcmd -S xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx -d xxxxxxx -U xxxxxxxxx -P xxxxxx```  with command prompt

Answer (score 1):

After doing some research I figured out my problem. I opened a SQL sever instance with cloudcluster which I have done before and successfully connected to with python and the pymysql module. The only difference was the sql type.

Previously I opened a MySQL Sever instance rather than a SQL Server. To connect to a SQL Server you would use pyodbc and to connect to a MySQL Server you would use pymysql or mysql.connector.

**You can not connect to a SQL instance using MySQL tools with python**

Even with the command line to connect to a SQL instance you would use the `sqlcmd` command and to connect to a MySQL Server you would use the `mysql` command.